# Appengine - Can a user import Yaml or Json file to update datastore with new values?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Imagine this scenario:
I made a small application in Python for Google App Engine for general use.

Users can login to my app, update their profile, change address and change the picture among many other things.

A user can export the models to PDF, YAML and JSON, save the file on his computer.

You can download any available format of your personal information.

**My question is:**

*Is It Possible for a user to upload files and update the datastore with new values?*

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Your users will be able to upload data in any file type *your application* can process.  You will, of course, need to write handlers to process the files and perform the updates.

There are also some size restrictions with [uploading, downloading,](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#Quotas_and_Limits) and [processing](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/overview.html#Quotas_and_Limits) data.  You will want to keep those in mind.

Comment: Sorry, but do not quite understand how I can do that. This is the same as Bulk Upload?
If so, users need only file YAML or JSON?, Or must have access to the SDK?

Comment: Unless you want to add users as developers to your app, you will need to write a handler to process the files and make changes to the datastore.  Your handler will support what ever file types the code you write can process.  JSON, YAML, and CSV are all very easy to deal with.  And your users will not need the SDK, only the schema, which you will specify (how you expect the file to be structured).